# Demora al cargar registros en datatable

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo una tabla con 3,000 registros, al cargar la pagina se demora demasiado. Tengo otra tabla con 16,000 registros y es peor porque si se demora mucho sale error.

Pueden ayudarme a solucionar ese problema. Leí por ahí que se puede solucionar con server side pero no me funciona y sale mensaje de error.

Tambien este ejemplo e igual:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
} );
} );
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: y como es la consulta SQL? por que ver tu petición en el frontend no nos dice mucho, estas trayendo toda esa data a la misma vez? como es que la estructuras en la vista para el user?

Comment: La consula es sin where ya q con el datatable se pagina.   SELECT * FROM producto

Comment: si amigo, pero tu pregunta es por que se demora la carga de datos, los cuales vienen por SQL del backend y si no vemos tu consulta entonces ni idea de que este fallando

Comment: como te digo mi consulta es esta SELECT * FROM producto , muestro todos los datos disponibles en mi tabla

Comment: $consulta = "SELECT idproducto, nombre_prod, idmarca, idsubcat, idempaque, precio_dcto, precio_v, ruta_imagen FROM producto WHERE activo='1'    ";
    $resultado = $conexion -> query($consulta);

Comment: $('#example23').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        //stateSave: true,
       //"processing": true,        
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ] 

    });